# Как лучше всего хранить данные о "друзьях" пользователя в базе данных?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Столкнулся с проблемой. Как лучше всего записывать "друзей" пользователя. Сначала я думал, что буду записывать так.

> ```
> user-id-one | user-id-two  
> ------------+------------  
>      1      |      2   
>      1      |      4  
>      1      |      10  
> ------------+-------------
> ```

Но когда понял, что когда на сайте будет хотя бы 5000 пользователей - база будет огромной.
Подскажите, как лучше всего хранить это в базе?

Comment: Что такое по вашему огромная база? Какую проблему вы решаете: нехватки места под данные или недостаточной производительности БД? Если не знаете ответов на эти вопросы, то может быть пока и не нужно искать лучший способ.

Comment: @a_gura Огромная база - это в смысле большой список для поиска. если будет много пользователей - будет очень много друзей "умножать на 40-100". и по 500 000 записям искать будет не очень быстро. а дальше - хуже.

Comment: @SnikersSurgut а вы поверяли? Если индекс представить двоичным деревом, то для поиска пользователя по идентификатору потребуется не более 13 операций сравнения для 5000 пользователей, а для 5 миллионов 23 операции. Т.е. при увеличении количества пользователей на несколько порядков (в нашем случае на 3), время поиска в индексе увеличится всего-лишь вдвое. Расчет довольно грубый, но он показывает, что вы пока зря беспокоитесь.

Сгенирируйте сами нужное количество записей и посмотрите на то, как изменится время выполнения запроса.

Comment: @a_gura про индексы можно по подробнее? А лучше ссылку на документацию "желательно русскую"

Comment: @SnikersSurgut думаете, MySQL дураками сделана? Поверьте, таблицы  с пятьюстами тысячами записей - это далеко не предел возможностей этой СУБД.

Comment: @SnikersSurgut начните например отсюда http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%28%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%29 Говорят у Томаса Кайта в книге "Oracle для профессионалов" тема индексов хорошо раскрыта.

Comment: Делайте как знаете, начатое дело доводите до конца, потом с начало наберите этих 5000 пользователей, потом увидите что будет дальше, а проблемы всегда можно решить.

Comment: @bemulima, если не задуматься о проблемах производительности на раннем этапе, например, при проектировании, то в последствие могут встать проблемы масштабируемости системы.
@SnikersSurgut, все-таки сделайте тестовую таблицу, поставьте индекс и заполните её хотя бы 10млн записей. Потом попробуйте делать выборки, вы будете удивлены результатом.

Comment: @DreamChild А если у меня ~ 30 млрд записей?
@bemulima Лучше, чтобы этих проблем не было, дабы не закрывать сайт на "технические работы"

Comment: @SnikersSurgut До проблем масштабируемости нужно еще дорасти. Чтобы это случилось, нужно сначала как минимум построить систему. Преждевременная оптимизация может сыграть с вами злую шутку. Кроме того, в плане масштабируемости, БД не единственное проблемное место. И в данный конкретный момент времени вы не можете предсказать, во что упретесь в будущем. Исходите из того, что знаете сейчас.

Comment: @SnikersSurgut вы хотя бы определитесь, о каких масштабах идет речь. Час назад выговорили о пятистах тысячах записей в таблице. Так вот для этих самых пятисот тысяч проблем вы не заметите (если не будете писать чересчур запутанных скриптов). В случае с тридцатью миллиардами конечно же заметите, но давайте честно - вы же, надеюсь, не станете врать, что делаете сайт, на котором несколько сотен миллионов пользователей? Иными словами, повторю сказанное выше - чтобы ставить перед собой такие проблемы, до них еще надо дорасти

Comment: @DreamChild лимит MySQL 3ТБ на один сервер/репликатор

Comment: @heavy_metal_fan к чему вы это? разве я где-то утверждал обратное?

Comment: `~30 млрд` -у фейсбук стока не будет...

Comment: @maris 3млн человек, у каждого по 10 000 друзей. этого хватит.
Я начал говорить за "друзей" потому что сейчас их делаю. Потом будут не только друзья, но и много всякого другого, что необходимо хранить в таблицах.

Comment: > 3млн человек, у каждого по 10 000 друзей. этого хватит

вашу ж мать, когда эти Денисы Поповы и BolgenOS'ы закончатся?

Comment: С моей точки зрения, повода для беспокойства нет. 5000 юзеров по 100 друзей = 500'000 коротких записей. Даже до миллиона не добираете, ерунда.
Это безотносительно адекватности структуры БД решаемой задаче, речь только про объём базы и производительность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> user-id-one | user-id-two  
> ------------+------------  
>      1      |      2   
>      1      |      4  
>      1      |      10  
> ------------+-------------
> ```

Такая таблица имеет смысл существования, но у неё есть свои недостатки.

1 из которых. Вот именно в данном примере мы видим что у пользователя **1** есть 3 друга.

допустим запрос будет выглядеть так

```
select user-id-two from friends where user-id-one=1
```

Получим список друзей пользователя 1. Вроде все бы ничего получили список. Но встает вопрос вот все друзья пользователя 1 приняли его в друзья.

тогда запрос вида

```
select user-id-two from friends where user-id-one=2
```

Должен возвратить список друзей пользователя 2, он это сделает, но сделает в том случае если только пользователь 2 первый предложил дружбу, тогда будет запись

> ```
> user-id-one | user-id-two  
> ------------+------------  
>      2      |      4   
>      2      |      3  
>      2      |      100  
> ------------+-------------
> ```

Но нет записи

> ```
> user-id-one | user-id-two  
> ------------+------------  
>      2      |      1   
> ------------+-------------
> ```

т.е. пользователю 2 не вылезет инфа что он дружит с пользователем 1.

Это самый существенный косяк.

Но его можно избежать так. Допустим пользователь 1 подал заявку на пользователя 2. создалась запись

> ```
> user-id-one | user-id-two  
> ------------+------------  
>      1      |      2
> ```

Когда пользователь 2 подтвердил заявку в друзья — создается симметричная запись.

> ```
> user-id-one | user-id-two  
> ------------+------------  
>      2      |      1
> ```

Но это увеличение БД ровно в 2 раза, что не есть хорошо.

Решение и тут есть, на мой взгляд.

Добавить 3е поле.

> ```
> user-id-one | user-id-two  | link
> ------------+--------------+-------  
>      2      |      1       |   0
> ```

link - в данном случае имеет значение 0 - т.е. пользователь 2 принял заявку в друзья.
1 - не принял. И сразу видно кто предложил дружбу, в данном случае пользователь 2.

Это уменьшит кол-во записей в таблице. Но запрос на выборку друзей тогда будет немного другой.

```
select user-id-one,user-id-two from friends where user-id-one=UID or user-id-two=UID // примерно так
```

Но тут опять же тупик в плане вытаскиваются 2 поля, и нужно проверять их значения, что для последующей оптимизации вообще не айс.

Есть вариант на мой взгляд простой, но [[@Mr Trololo](/users/11207/mr-trololo)](/users/11207/mr-trololo) Вы ему за ответ поставили минусы. Но он в чем-то прав товарищи.

Рассмотрим пример. Есть у нас таблица

> ```
> user-id-one | user-id-two  
> ------------+--------------
>      2      |      array("1","2","3","4");                
>      1      |      array("10","12","3","6");                
>      3      |      array("23","2","5","6");
> ```

В чем фишка, мы храним в поле не просто строку **2,4,55,123** а массив ID пользователей, у каждого он свой, на каждого пользователя 1 запись в БД, расти такая таблица будет несомненно но уже меньше чем предыдущий вариант.
В чем прикол массива

- Получить список пользователей просто
- Получить список общих друзей тоже. Как? **array_intersect** возвращает общие значения из нескольких массивов.
- Добавить/удалить/изменить значение в массиве достаточно просто.
- В такой записи можно указывать и отношение связей, добавлять при этом доп поле не нужно, все в массиве. Как? Допустим есть значение 23. Оно положительное, значит примем за правило, если в массиве ID пользователя записан положительно, значит он предложил дружбу, если отрицательное, то ему предложили. **array("-23","2","-5","6");**  двоих пригласил он двое пригласили его.
- Как-то нужно учитывать принятие в друзья!? Да, не вопрос сделайте в этом же массиве перед ID пользователя **array("?23","2","?5","?6");**  знак **?** это значит что решение о дружбе еще не принято. Ну или другой знак, символ.+ есть 2 варианта вы добавляете и вас добавляют, если вы добавляете тогда ставьте **?** один знак, если вас добавляют **??** два знака
- Да при таком раскладе есть дублирование информации, но вытащить её в последствии проще.
- Хранить её можно в сериализованном массиве, в JSON кому как удобнее. Но в данном случае именно массив это чтобы работала **array_intersect** она есть в php.
- Найти кто добавил в друзья меня

`select user-id-two from friends where user-id-one=UID` // получим список всех пользователей
Далее из массива вычленить отрицательные значения. Да скажите что это геморрой, но в данном случае вы же можете этот запрос закешировать! И данные у вас всегда под рукой!

- Тоже самое и с веткой кого я добавил в друзья
- Ну и конечно же те кто еще не подтвердили заявку от Вас, и кому вы не подтвердили заявку.

Примерное описание такой. Давайте кидайте помидоры! Только свежие, я их люблю :)

В общем сначала скушайте эту информацию, думаю это один из правильных вариантов решения вопроса о дружбах на сайтах. Это один из вариантов решения, он не претендует на правильность, т.к. только что написал всю эту **многабукф** сюда. Это просто представление решения проблемы

Comment: Третье поле, у меня, разумеется есть "подтверждение"
и с запросом я проблему легко решил использую логические операции "or" и "and"

Comment: Shrek, блин. Ну ты чё? Убирай последние два абзаца - все ощущение от ответа портят.

Comment: Да нормально, пусть будут. Мне непонятно почему принят непонятный ответ.

Comment: Потому что у человека голова болит из-за тех проблем, которые потенциально могут возникнуть через пять-семь лет.

Comment: @Khvorostin Вот именно. Зачем тупить сейчас когда оно не нужно, и беспокоиться о том чего может и не будет?!

Я к лету открывать буду свой проект и пока ни разу не задумался о разделении сервера БД и всего остального т.к. не вижу в течении полугода-года резкого скачка посетителей и глобальной активности в сервисе. Да и сервер сможет выдержать наплыв достаточно большого кол-ва пользователей. Какой смысл бежать впереди паровоза?! Я уже сейчас знаю, что при большом кол-ве пользователей онлайн буду переделывать не только разнос серверов с БД,а еще и код, и файлы и прочее.но думать сейчас об этом.

Comment: А ведь Синьер @Shrek дело говорит....

Comment: По поводу ответа. А почему нельзя сделать две таблицы: в одной записываются друзья, в другой только заявки. Как только человек, к которому предложили дружбу, подтверждает заявку, запись переносится в таблицу с друзьями. Т.е. оба человека друг у друга в друзьях, и никакого увеличения в 2 раза объема данных не будет.

Answer (score 2):

автор, я не знаю, насколько серьезны ваши намерения насчет трех миллионов и десяти тысяч друзей у каждого из них, но в таком случае вам имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону шардинга. 
Почитайте об этом например [тут](http://highload.com.ua/index.php/2009/05/06/%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86/), [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129780/) или даже [тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29)
Все эти затеи с хранением всего списка друзей в одной строке лучше забыть - вы с ним не сможете сделать вообще ничего без убойных в плане падения производительности костылей

Comment: И это правильный ответ? *озирается по сторонам*

Comment: @shrek Почитай все комментарии - поймёшь

Comment: Да, это бред.
Вопрос не про то как делать шардинг, а как хранить связи.
В общем это один из вариантов ответа, но он нифига не раскрывает ответ, это послесловие к хорошему ответу и не более того.

\+ ко всему там еще и редис в одной из ссылок стоит, так что не надо путать мускул и редис. Две совершенно разные штуки.

Так что не считаю этот ответ правильным.

Answer (score 0):

Можно расширить вопрос и получить еще один подход к решению вопроса с друзьями. Допустим, надо в базе данных хранить [синонимы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%E8%ED%EE%ED%E8%EC%FB). Тоже взаимные связи, но не *один-к-одному*, а смесь вариантов *один-к-одному* и *один-ко-многим*.

Имеем таблицу слов [words] - аналог таблицы пользователей:

```
id | term
---|----------------------
 1 | алый
 2 | багровый
 3 | багряный
 4 | кавалерия
 5 | конница
 6 | красный
 7 | смелый
 8 | храбрый
```

Создаем дополнительную таблицу [connections] (тонкости реализации опущены):

```
id_conn | id_term
--------|--------
     1  |      1 
     1  |      2 
     1  |      3 
     1  |      6 
     2  |      4 
     2  |      5 
     3  |      7 
     3  |      8
```

Суть этого подхода в том, что есть понятие связи (круга друзей), в которой может быть **два и более** элементов. Такой подход совершенно исключает дублирование информации: отзеркаливать данные (user-id-one, user-id-two) нет необходимости.

---

Более гибкий подход - фиксировать не круг друзей, а связь **двух** человек. Добавляем в таблицу [connections] поле [link]:

```
id_conn | id_user | link
--------|---------|------
     1  |      1  | TRUE
     1  |      2  | TRUE
     2  |      3  | TRUE
     2  |      4  | FALSE
```

Можно и ещё более приближенный к действительности вариант сделать:

Типы связей:

```
id | type
---|------
 1 | супруги
 2 | друзья
 3 | тусили как-то
```

Пользователи:

```
id | name
---|------
 1 | Ромео
 2 | Меркуцио
 3 | Джульетта
```

Связи (главная таблица):

```
id | conn | c_type
---|------|-------
 1 |    1 |      1
 2 |    2 |      2
 3 |    3 |      3
```

Связи (дочерняя таблица):

```
id | id_conn | id_user | link
---|---------|---------|------
 1 |       1 |      1  | TRUE
 2 |       1 |      3  | TRUE
 3 |       2 |      1  | TRUE
 4 |       2 |      2  | TRUE
 5 |       3 |      3  | TRUE
 6 |       3 |      1  | FALSE
```

Comment: В данном случае непонятно кто кого добавил в друзья, как вытащить общих друзей?

Comment: @Shrerk, это верно. Мой подход более статичен и просто фиксирует круг друзей. Вариант: фиксировать предложение дружить в отдельной таблице. Вот вытащить общих друзей как раз не проблема. Круг друзей - это группа ВЗАИМНЫХ друзей. Собственно, нужно взять всех из круга кроме двух конкретных пользователей. Сейчас добавлю еще один нюанс собственно в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сделать так же, как вы и решили. Но вместо того, чтобы каждый раз дергать БД на наличие друзей, кэшируйте эти данные (Mongo, Redis, MemcaheDB, etc). И вытягивайте оттуда.

Если вас пугает размер БД, да, можете разбить ее (как сказали выше). Но все равно кэшируйте. А при изменении списка друзей (удаление, добавление) - сделайте апдейт кэша.

Я бы сделал так

Comment: у него явно в тегах стоит MYSQL. зачем предлагать человеку монго и редис - ему до этого еще далеко. Он сначала купит много серверов, потом поймет что сделал не так как надо и тогда будет смотреть в сторон монго, редис и остального.

Answer (score 0):

шардинг я делал [так](http://highloadblog.ru/articles/11.html). Он применим как к системе сообщений, так и к профайлам пользователей. Пользователи тоже надо шардить.

В настоящее время, проект имеет более 20 млн пользователей (больше к сожалению я собрать не смог, контакт круче...), в пике (19-22час) 25тыс запросов в мин.

- данные о пользователей шардятся на несколько БД (всего 16), физических серверов два, скоро будем разносить на 8, не увеличивая число баз.
- данные о друзьях хранятся как список id, в той шарде, на которой находятся профайл  пользователя
- запросы на дружбу посылаются через очередь, описано [тут](http://highloadblog.ru/articles/2.html)

в общем по ссылкам в блоге найдете много полезного, чего можно применить. Скоро напишу статью, как работать с Пользователями и друзьями

Comment: @akalend, это вы про ТопФэйс?

Comment: нет, но в топфейсе сделано почти также

Answer (score -2):

Ну если не хотите создавать отдельную таблицу, теоретически можно добавить поле "friends" в запись о пользователе, и хранить там данные в виде "2,4,55,123", а упаковывать-распаковывать уже в приложении. Или по такому же принципу сделать таблицу с полями id и friends. Но идеологически это "некрасивые" решения.

Comment: это не просто "некрасиво", это адов бред. Что-то наподобие "отпилить руку, если заболел палец"

Comment: @DreamChild нет, не адов бред. Это даже может работать быстрее, т.к. нужно вернуть одну запись, а не несколько. 

Другое дело, что это не ответ на вопрос "как лучше?"

Comment: Если человека пугает "огромная база", то другого способа сократить число записей я не вижу.

Comment: быстрее? вы смеетесь что ли? А работать с этим  вы как будете? Каждый раз парсить из этой строки массив целочисленных идентификаторов, а потом искать в этом массиве тот, который вам нужен? А если вам, скажем, нужны все друзья данного пользователя, проживающие в Москве? А если все друзья всех друзей? А если вы вдруг захотите удалить половину друзей из этого списка? Не многовато ли таких дивных манипуляций со строками? А join по идентификаторам друзей вы как делать будете? И таких вопросов можно придумать еще сто миллионов.

Comment: То, что вы пытаетесь доказать, и так ясно. Но вопрос был не о том, как сделать лучше, а о хранении.

Comment: @DreamChild Слишком много если. И нет, я не смеюсь. Это может быть быстрее ровно для одной задачи - получить список идентификаторов (применительно к примеру в вопросе).

Comment: И как же сделать "красиво"
Не хотелось бы потом перестраивать структуру базы данных

Comment: Слишком много если

А вы как думали? Положить, извините за выражение, болт на все эти "если"? А что касается "ровно для одной задачи" и "получить список идентификаторов" - зачем он нужен без возможности сделать с ним что-либо еще? А любое "что-либо еще" будет сопряжено с огромными трудностями

    Но вопрос был не о том, как сделать лучше, а о хранении

и что вы будете делать с этим "хранением"? Просто хранить?

Comment: Вопрос был "Как лучше всего записывать". Это касается хранения, чтения, изменения и удаления.

Comment: >  Это касается хранения, чтения, изменения и удаления

так вот о том и речь. Как в этом случае вы будете что-либо читать/изменять/удалять?

Comment: в том то и дело, что при записи "1,2,13,1024,14444" нужно всю строку переписывать.
Решил сделать так, как писал в заголовке.
Кто-нибудь - вынесите идею с индексами из комментариев.